# issue trying to use combine value to get a value from a datasource

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a summary report with a multiples dataset used in differents lookup, I know the lookup compare single values only, I need to compare double value in a datasets and return the value, I'm trying to using a combined source in a first parameter of lookup but I'm not sure if it will be work

```
dataset1
name  team value
----------------
john  team1   3
john  team2   4
mark  team1   2
jane  team2   1
```

I want to use lookup for this dataset using  name and team together to build a unique key and get the correct value like a 
lookup for "john+team1" and get the value 3

Any help or idea???

Comment: Can you add the queries for your datasets to your question? It looks as though it would be simpler to do the lookup in a single SQL query that returns your other data, rather than combine data from multiple datasets.

Comment: Are you asking whether a primary key or a foreign key or an index can consist of two or more columns? If so, the answer is, yes, any of them can. The term used for such things is *composite* or *compound*, like *composite primary key* or *compound index*.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to compare the 2 datasets within SQL rather than trying to do it in SSRS? Temp table1 would be name etc

Write one massive query to combine all of the data, that was it's easier/ quicker to use and it can be used in one table